Reading a table from access database (Integer column has NA values)
When trying to read a table "results" from an access database using pandas_access library "EPFDResults_320520290_2023_06_27_03_26_42_USER.mdb", I get an error ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 4. The mdb database, if interested can be downloaded for free from the ITU agency website.
The operating system is Linux (Amazon Linux AMI) and I tried "pyodbc" with no success on the Linux OS.
import pandas_access as mdb
itu_results = "~/source_data/EPFDResults_320520290_2023_06_27_03_26_42_USER.mdb"
df_epfdperc = mdb.read_table(itu_results, "results")

The error is

ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 4

Not sure how to eliminate this error.
I expect to read the table.

Not familiar with this package which may not be maintained (PyPI page indicates June 2016) but why not use the well-known and maintained pyodbc and pandas read_sql? Search the many such asked questions here on SO.

BTW - Do you have MS Access installed for a PC or Office/Office365? If you have a PC, you can install free Access runtime/engine with driver for ODBC connections.

my OS is Linux, I think pyodbc is mostly Windows.
